# Refresh ApplicationContext or single bean by changing variable in context file

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-boot

We have a bean

```
class MonetDrop(){

    def chance

    def doDrop(){
     println("Your chance to win ${chance} %")
    }
}
```

In context.groovy initialize bean and set value for property 'chance':

```
beans{
     monetDrop(MonetDrop){
        chance = 50
    }
}
```

I need to refresh bean when I change "chance" variable in context.
I can use also xml or java config, and move this bean to separate config file.
**How can I manage to refresh bean when config(!) changes in working application?**
App on Java 1.8/Groovy 2.4.4 + Springboot

Comment: Where do you keep your configuration?

Comment: @MarcoTedone my real config working. i ceep it in $project_dir/config. It doesn't matter where, main question still open

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the bean and updated it manually? You can `@Autowired` the `BeanFactory` and try to update the specified bean or just `@Autowired` the exact bean.

For example:

```
@Component
public class MonetDropUpdater {
    @Autowired
    private MonetDrop drop;

    public void update () {
        // update drop.chance
    }
}
```

If `chance` has been updated, remember to update `MonetDrop#chance`.

Another way to `refresh` this bean is through annotation `@Refresh`.

At the end, if `MonetDrop` is a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean, you can just include `spring-boot-actuator` to refresh it with `spring-cloud-config-client`.

Comment: I haven't access to bean on production, when application working as JAR. can only change properties or config files. 
I will learn about spring-boot-actuator. thanks